# WP Menu walker function to display parent description and wrap parent in own div

Tags: wordpress, function, menu, navigation, parent-child

Anyone know how to write a custom walker function for wp_nav_menu that will...

1) Display the item description for parent items only.

2) Wrap the parent item (title, link and description) in it's own div *only* if it has children.

*(I've simplified the div's and ul's to have no classes)*

```
<div>
  <ul>

    <!-- Parent With Children -->
    <li class="has_children">
      <div class="first-level">
        <a>Parent Item</a>
        <span class="desc">Description</span>
      </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu level-0">
          <li class="odd"><a>Child Item</a></li>
          <li class="even NO HAS_CHILDREN"><a>Child Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu level-1">
               <li class="odd"><a>Child Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="odd"><a>Child Item</a></li>
          <li class="even"><a>Child Item</a></li>
          <li class="odd"><a>Child Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Parent Without Children -->
    <li>
     <div class="first-level">
      <a>Parent Item</a>
      <span class="desc">Description</span>
     </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

^^ All of the above classes and ID's should be *IN ADDITION* to those which are already in wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is based on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/add-has-children-class-to-parent-li-when-modifying-walker-nav-menu) and [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu)

```
    class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
     function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
{
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
        $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    }
    return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array('sub-menu','level-' . $display_depth);
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {

        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );

        if ($args->has_children && $depth == 0){
        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' has_children"';
        }else{
         ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';  
        }

        $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>" ;
        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // insert description for top level elements only
        // you may change this
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
            ? '<span class="desc">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</span>' : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
if ( $depth == 0 ) {//top level items
            $item_output = $args->before
            ."<div class='first-level'>"
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a>'
            . $args->link_after
            . $description
            . '</div>'
            . $args->after;
        }else{//everything else
        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after
            . $args->after;
        }
        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );
    }

}
```

and then call it with the walker

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new Description_Walker )); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. Hmm, it seems that you've actually fully replaced the parents li tags with the 'parent' div? Any way of still keeping the li containers like my code example in the original question?

Comment: @LukeEtheridge oh sorry i didn't understand - i updated my answer

Comment: Also, ALL parents must have the 'parent' div class AND display their description whether they have children or not. I still want to have the 'has_children' class though for all those with children (as my example). Is this possible?

Comment: @LukeEtheridge if its a parent then it has to have children - if it has no children then it isnt a parent

Comment: Understood. Forget the word 'parent' for a sec, I would like all first level categories to be wrapped in their own div AND display their description. I've edited my code above to show this.

Comment: @LukeEtheridge ok i updated my answer fully - hope this helps

Comment: Mark you're a true genius! One other thing - I still want the first-level's containing 'li' to possess all other generic classes AS WELL AS the additional 'has_children' class, and any others I choose to add in the WP Menu's configuration....

Comment: Like so... <li id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-offer_category has_children">

Comment: I also only want 'first-level' items to be wrapped in the 'has_children' li if it has children. So, for li's which have children any deeper than the first-level, they get the regular classes.

Comment: In additon to the above comments I would also like ALL li's that are within sub-menu ul's to have 'odd' and 'even' classes. I'll update my code above.

Comment: Sorry to mess you about Mark. You've been amazing so far. I've finally figured out exactly what I'm after and I've edited my code. ALL of the custom classes that I want above are still to include the generic Wordpress menu classes. As you can see I've also added 'level-$depth' to all 'sub-menu' ul's

Comment: @LukeEtheridge I updated again - I got it to display the level number but i cant figure out the odd even classes. maybe ill give a try later

Comment: Mark thanks for all your help on this. Literally wouldn't know where I'd be without your help. All I require is those odd and even classes now.

Comment: Any clues on the odd/even classes Mark? I've been looking EVERYWHERE to no avail :(

Comment: @LukeEtheridge [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/majpage-menu-class-extender/) should be what your'e looking for - it will work with the custom walker

Comment: Hey Mark, I didn't want to have to use a plugin for this, is there any way to workout how the plugin creator is achieving this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mark - Hi Mark, I have a big problem with a walker that I'm trying to do, and it seems that no one can really seem to give an answer. I was wondering if you wouldn't mind possibly taking a look at my situation, and trying to work out (or help me to work out) how to build a walker to do what I'm after?

Comment: @Lee sure - wheres your question?

Comment: @Mark My question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876273/how-can-i-display-the-parent-menu-items-description-using-wordpress-walkers - There is one answer already, but it hasn't worked at all.

Comment: @Mark - Have also added this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251897/how-can-i-add-parent-menu-description-to-my-wordpress-menu - That might be easier for you to understand, thanks.