# How can I display the parent menu item's description using Wordpress walkers?

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

Is there any way to pass a variable from start_el to start_lvl? I want to place the menu description in the wrapper of the submenu items.

```
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'><div class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div></div>\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<div class='clear'></div></ul>\n";
    }
}
```

I've tried to store the description as a variable in start_el, and access it using global in start_lvl... but it returns nothing.

I'm really desperate for help on this, as so far I've had no results, or responses to this question in terms of answers.

Can someone please help me with this? There are definitely some of you who know how to use the Wordpress walker menu.

Comment: If you want description with every element of navigation then you would have to use `start_el`, have a look at this tutorial : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-menu-descriptions-in-your-wordpress-themes/

Comment: @SyedQarib I'm not looking to add it to every element, just the first sub menu that's shown (the walker I've got at the moment correctly adds the image div that I can use, but I just need to find a way to use the menu description in that function)

Comment: @SyedQarib Do you know enough about the walkers to try and go through this issue?

Comment: @SyedQarib Are you able to help me try to work this out please?

Comment: Sorry, was out for some time.. here is something you can try.. as `start_lvl` runs before `start_el`, so you can not pass value from el to lvl.. try doing the whole thing in `start_el` and add the description and image with first element only ..

Comment: Would you be able to provide as an answer? Maybe in a basic form with a comparison that shows the difference between El and lvl

Comment: Check if this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu

Comment: Have already seen that, but it just seems to add the description to each sub menu item. Are you able to provide an answer?

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to achieve then.. you can control the descriptions from WP admin panel.. add descriptions for those only whom you want descriptions to be displayed with ..

Comment: I have a menu description added int he Admin for the parent menu item (the first level nav item). I want this description to be displayed inside the first sub-menu ul item for each parent item. So I believe this would need the start_el to include all of the children menu items but to only show the description of the parent menu item, and not the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution to this question that seemed to go unanswered for days here - [How can I add parent menu description to my Wordpress menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251897/how-can-i-add-parent-menu-description-to-my-wordpress-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to use this code and it will display the parent description.
Steps for using of it.
1: Copy the below class and past into the functions.php file.
2: Call the menu like

```
 wp_nav_menu(array(
      'menu_id'=>'',
      'menu_class'=>'',
      'container'=>'',
      'theme_location'=>'#enter theme location#',
      'walker'=> new customize_menu_walker()
    ));
<br/>
```

3:See the result.

```
class customize_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

          // $dbclasses=$item->classes;
           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $dbclasses=$class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';



            $item_output = $args->before;

             //specially for two menu
             //specially for two menu
           //convert string to array
           $dbclassesArr = explode(" ",$dbclasses);

           $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

           if(in_array("menu-item-has-children", $dbclassesArr)){
             $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';//description display here.
           }

            $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= ' '.'</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            }
}
```

Now after updating this function, your menu will show the parent menu description.
Here is the code.

Thanking you.

Comment: Okay, whilst I'm pleased that you've given an answer, I don't really think you read my question, as your answer provides literally loads of errors stating that $description is an undefined variable. Just to be clear, not menu item has a description.. which is what I believe this class is outputting. Correct?

Comment: Placed an isset around the output of $description, which cleared the errors. But, this is meaning that no description is ever outputted. Also, when adding the start_lvl and end_lvl that I had originally, it completely changes the styling of the menu, and displays all items in a nested list.