# Access sub-menu description in end_lvl (Wordpress Walker_Nav_Menu)

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I'm currently working on a custom WordPress sub-menu; I added some custom html code to it using Walker_Nav_Menu.

I want to access the fields `description` and `attr_title` inside the method `end_lvl`. Is that possible?

Same as this but in `end_level`:
[How can I display the parent menu item's description using Wordpress walkers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876273/how-can-i-display-the-parent-menu-items-description-using-wordpress-walkers)

```
class BENZ_Walker_Nav_Menu_ACC extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL) {
        if( 0 == $depth ) {
            $output .= sprintf('
            <div class="sub-menu-bottom-section">
                <span class="sub-menu-title">%s</span>
                <p class="sub-menu-under-title">%s</p>
            </div>', title, description);
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "{$indent}</ul>\n";
    } 
}
```