# How can I add parent menu description to my Wordpress menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

I've entered the description into the parent menu items in Wordpress, but they're not showing on my theme.

I know that a walker class can be used to make changes to the menu, but I don't know how to code it.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <!-- REPEATING MENU ITEM START -->
        <li class="menu-parent-item"><a>Face</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-image-container">
                <div class="menu-image"></div>
                <div class="menu-description">[Face menu item description]</div>
            </li>
            <li class="heading">Face</li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 1</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 2</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 3</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="heading">Ear</li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 1</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 2</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 3</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="heading">Eyes</li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 1</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 2</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- REPEATING MENU ITEM END -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, I only want the description of the parent menu item to be shown, but it needs to be within the first `ul.sub-menu` within the parent list item.

How could I code a walker that uses `start_lvl`, `start_el` and `end_lvl` to handle this efficiently?

Comment: can you go through how you will be populating this in the backend? what is the second instance of face?

Comment: The second instance of Face, along with Ear, and Eyes, are headings that I've created by inserting menu links, with empty href tags, and added a class called 'heading' - You can see this presented by visiting http://dev.bellavou.co.uk - Hopefully that will explain a little bit if you look at the navigation menu. If you inspect the dropdowns, underneath the large menu images, is a description tag. This is where I want the parent menu description to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the menu to display as before, whilst adding the parent menu description exactly where I wanted by simply just adding to what I already had.

I already had a walker that created the sub-menu image container, and the description container

```
// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'></div></li>\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<li><div class='clear'></div></li></ul>\n";
    }
}
```

Then I managed to find a function that uses `start_el` and could assign the description to a variable, but not output it, then just output the `$item_output` as normal.

```
function add_menu_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    $description = __( $item->post_content );
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_menu_description', 10, 4);
```

Of course now I needed to use `$description` within my other submenu walker function, so I just created a global variable in both, and the output is exactly what I'm after!

**FINAL OUTPUT**

```
function add_menu_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    global $description;
    $description = __( $item->post_content );
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_menu_description', 10, 4);

// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        global $description;
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'>".$description."</div></li>\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<li><div class='clear'></div></li></ul>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ok i'm not sure if this is fool proof but here's my try:

so you would need to make sure description is on in the admin menu console (in the 'screen options' dropdown)

Your first menu item should be Face then Face again as its child then sub neu items as children to that.

Hope this helps!

**in your functions.php**

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
     function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
{
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
        $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    }
    return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth=0, $args=array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array('sub-menu');
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}
    function start_el(&$output, $item,  $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
    {

        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );

        if ($args->has_children && $depth == 0){
        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="menu-parent-item"';
        }else if($depth == 1){
         ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="heading"';
        }else{
         ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) .'"';  
        }

        $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>" ;
        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // insert description for top level elements only
        // you may change this
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
            ? '<div class="menu-description">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</div>' : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        if (  $depth == 0) {//top level items
         $item_output = $args->before.$title.'</li><ul class="sub-menu"><li class="menu-image-container"><div class="menu-image"></div>'.$description.'</li>';  
        }
        else if(  $depth == 1){
             $item_output = $args->before.$title.'</li>';
        }
        else{//everything else
        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after
            . $args->after;
        }
        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );

    }
}
```

**in your header (or wherever your menu is)**

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation"><?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => 'menu-main-menu-container', 'menu_id' => 'menu-main-menu', 'walker' => new Description_Walker )); ?></nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But next question is, I already have a walker in place that uses start_lvl and end_lvl to help style and build the large dropdown menus that appear. Will this need to be replaced, or will your walker work with those functions also?

Comment: im not sure what your walkers are doing but this one will add the menu exactly like you mocked up in HTML in the question. Just save a backup before proceeding.

Comment: Okay, i'll try this. It essentially just added the divs for the image and description. I then just floated them to the right of the container.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely right, although it's on the right tracks. It's outputting as 'Face' as the only top level menu item, with all the others inside that (including Body, Breast). Actually, let me expand my mockup above to include the other menu items.

Comment: Okay, have updated my mockup example. Sorry about that, that's my mistake. So there are parent menu items, which inside the `<li>`s have sub menus, with more links inside. The description of the parent, needs to be within the first `<ul class="sub-menu">` of the parent menu item.

Comment: @Lee I have tried every possible thing I could - Doesnt seem to work. The only way this could work is if you get the description off the parent menu and add it to the submenu output.

Comment: As far as I know, that can't be done. You can't store it as a variable in start_el and then use it in start_lvl. Surely it can't be this much of a hard task? It doesn't sound like a very uncommon idea. But thanks anyway

Comment: I've figured it out! I'll be posting an answer shortly

Comment: @Lee great! can you at least upvote my answer for the effort? :)

Comment: I sure will! Thanks for the help