# Wordpress walker is working, but not correctly

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker

Last year I managed to add additional elements into my Wordpress menu by using a walker. ([How can I add parent menu description to my Wordpress menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251897/how-can-i-add-parent-menu-description-to-my-wordpress-menu))

Currently, the walker look slike this in my functions file:

```
// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        global $description;
        $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'>".$description."</div></li>";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "<li><div class='clear'></div></li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I wanted to do was to add an image and a short description to each first level sub menu on the website: www.bellavou.co.uk

If you visit this site, you'll see it looks fine, because I've used CSS to hide all the other instances I don't want shown. But if you inspect, you'll see that a menu-image container is added for every submenu within the parent menu items.

i.e. Inside 'Face', there is a menu-item div within the 'Face', 'Eye' and 'Ear' submenu, as well as the one that's showing inside the main sub-menu.

I only want the main one to show, and I Think this is achieved by changing the depth settings, but I've tried and it's not making any changes.

What can I do to only create the new sub-menu once within the top level parent sub-menu?

UPDATE & SOLVED:

Turns out I was thinking along the right lines, in terms of depth where the rules get applied. But didn't think about the existing sub menus I have.

```
// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if(0 == $depth) {
            global $description;
            $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'>".$description."</div></li>";
        } else {
            $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
        }
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if(0 == $depth) {
            $output .= "<li><div class='clear'></div></li></ul>";
        } else {
            $output .= "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

This has now fixed it with only the image div appearing once at the very top of the parent sub-menu, and the others just displaying their child items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understand your question correctly. If you wish this image containers only for one level, then you can check `if ( $depth == $desired_level)`

```
// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if ( $depth == 0 ) {
            global $description;
            $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'>".$description."</div></li>";
        } else {
           $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
        }

    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if ( $depth == 0 ) {
            $output .= "<li><div class='clear'></div></li></ul>";
        } else {
           $output .= "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether $depth should be 0 or 1 in your case, try it.

Comment: That's what I've been trying, and although it seems to make a close change, it's not right. The closest I get is exactly what you've put, but then it gets rid of the sub menus within the main sub menu, like 'Face', 'Ear', 'Eye'.. what happens it he headings and menu links are all individual `li` items

Comment: Saying that, I've realised why. But your comment really helped me realise this, so I'll add an extra part to my question, and will then mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Of course you a right. I will correct my answer accordingly. Thank you.